# Is this a 4:2 Multiplexor?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

[image]

My instructor has been insisting that the multiplexor in the picture above is a 4:2 mux not a 4:1 mux and that my textbook (Digital Design and Computer Architecture by Harris) is incorrect and that there are typos in the text. From what I have learned, this is indeed a 4:1 mux, because there are four inputs and one output.

He also says that a 4:1 or (4:2) mux has four data inputs and one two bit selector. However, from what is shown above it also seems that it should have two separate 1 bit selectors.

I am asking which is correct because I would genuinely like to know and also because I need to implement one in JLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 4 different combination of S1 and S2 (1bit selectors), you select one of the four inputs and get that selected input on the output. So **4** tells you that you can get four different values at the output, and 1 tells you that you can have just one at a time on the output. I hope its now clearer whats happening here.

Your picture is 4:1 multiplexor, and if I'm right 4:2 multiplexor looks like this

[image]

Used from [The Multiplexer](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html)

Comment: 4 output combinations? Don't you mean 4 input combinations? (00, 01, 10, or 11)?

Comment: And is there a such thing as a 4:2 multiplexor?

Comment: How many bits are the selectors (Aren't they 1 bit each)? Contrary to what my professor is saying

Comment: Yes, my wrong, you can select one of four inputs with S1 and S2 :)

Comment: @ohbrobig: Look in your book; it's called a multiplex _E_ r, not a multiplex _O_ r and yes, there is such a thing as a 4:2 multiplexer. It's a 4:1 multiplexer with two switched  mutually exclusive outputs.

Comment: @ohbrobig I corrected my answer take a look

Comment: You actually show a dual 2:1 multiplexer. While it's also colloquially (and incorrectly) called a 4:2 multiplexer, actual 4:2 multiplexers are 4:1 multiplexers with 1:2 output driver stages, as used for clock distribution ICs for example.

Answer (score 0):

In Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) 4:1 refers to four_inputs-one_output.

Calling four_input-two_controls a 4:2 mux is weird because you always need log2(n) control signals to choose one of n, so this information is superfluous. In contrast to that it is very interesting to know to how many signals the input gets reduced (a 4:1 mux is NOT equal a 4:2 mux and has different applications!).